# Magento 2.2.6 - Invalid factory was registered for this instance type

Tags: magento2, factory

I have transferred my Magento project to live server and just changed database connectivity credentials. No other change.

and if I run any Magento command

then I get the following error:

> While attempting to create viewjsonstrategy(alias: ViewJsonStrategy) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.

[image: Error image]

I have deleted cache files from `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`, `pub/static/frontend`, `pub/static/adminpanel`, `generated/code`, `generated/metadata` but no success.

Please guide if anybody has any solution.

Comment: Please check your php version is compatible?

Comment: It's 7.1.31. It should work. right?

Comment: try to check with compile command.